# Angular Routing not working in prodution mode

Tags: angular

I'm having a problem when running an angular4 app on prodution mode.
On developer mode everything works ok.

I have an app that displays a login page, authenticates and then redirects do /dashboard.
This works ok on dev mode but when prodution mode is activated the login page authenticates, then calls the navigateByUrl('/dashboard') that aparently does nothing...
here's the code for the login.component.ts onsubmit method:

```
this._authservice.postAuthentication(value.name, value.password)
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log('Antes navigateByUrl');
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
      console.log('Depois navigateByUrl');
    },
    err => {
      console.log('Erro de Auth');
      this.onSubmitError = true;
    });
}
```

Both console.log before and after navigateByUrl work fine but no navigation occurs.
Any idea why this happens only in prodution mode?

Aditional notes:

- DevTools show no error message
- Routing has path: 'dashboard', on the Routes array(and works on dev)
- index.html has
- Trying to access a route via direct url doesn't work.
- Tried Augury but it always claims that the app is in prod mode(dunno why, cause it's not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem!

I had an legacy AuthGuard hidden away and loaded on to the providers somewhere above on the DI.

On dev mode the correct AuthGuard was loaded but after built and deployed on the http-server the legacy AuthGuard was used cancelling any navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this method:

```js
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
```

Comment: tried it, but problem still happens. NavigateCancel is show on trace with an empty reason

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have to do with production apps needing to be set up to fallback to index.html and using navigateByUrl. When you put in a new url the server will look for that directory and not find it because its actually something Angular should be using, so you need to tell it just to serve index.html and Angular routing will pick it up from there.

Here's the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) about that

The way to set it up depends on how you are hosting your production app

Comment: changed from navigatebyUrl to navigate and the problem still exists.  
<br/>
On route tracing I can see that '/dashboard' is recognized on RoutesRecognized.  
<br/>
NavigationCancel is called after the route is recognized and returns a empty reason

Answer (score 0):

check if mentioned route is part of router-module.

Comment: I activated enableTracing on the router and got the following output:

 - RoutesRecognized(id: 3, url: '/dashboard', urlAfterRedirects: '/dashboard', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'dashboard', path:'dashboard') { Route(url:'', path:'') }  }  }  } )
 -   Router Event: t
 -   NavigationCancel(id: 3, url: '/dashboard')

Looks like it finds the route but then cancels with empty reason.

Comment: I wonder how this could happen. may be you can try 
** this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);**rather than **this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');**.
Good Luck.